# google+1 follow button click response is not show

Tags: google-plus-one

I just added GooglePlus one button in my website. I just want to see a response message onclick on the button.I tried but it is not showing. Can anyone help me please.

Thanks
Rasel Ahmed.

Answer (score 0):

You will find all configuration Options [here](https://developers.google.com/+/web/+1button/)